# Why is Broschi's "Son qual nave ch'agitata" in Vivaldi's opera "L'oracolo in Messenia"?

Tags: classical-music, baroque

It's supposed to be composed by Riccardo Broschi but i realized it was on the list of the album of the opera L'oracolo in Messenia by Vivaldi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enclosed booklet offers this information (Frédéric Delaméa, 2012):

> Only the libretto of the Viennese Oracolo survives, and bears witness to an extensive process of revision which took the final version still further from the Giacomellian model with the insertion of arias derived from Zeno's original libretto, numbers from earlier operas from Vivaldi (such as Merope's great act 2 scene 1 aria, 'No, non meriti pietà', from Griselda) and arias from other composers (such as Trasimede's act 2 Scene 7 aria 'Son qual nave', most likely borrowed from Broschi's Artaserse). These changes show Vivaldi's willingness to create a work calculated to appeal to a new public, as well as illustrating the multifacted nature of his genius and revealing him to be an incredibly versatile musician, who could turn his hand to composition, revision and compilation with equal flair.

So Vivaldi tried to find get a new patron by impressing him, a plan which didn't work out, since Charles VI died suddenly after eating poisonous mushrooms on 20th of October, 1740.

Answer (score 0):

Aria di bravura named "Son qual nave ch'agitata" has composed by neapolitan compositor Riccardo Brioschi in the year 1734.

In the track list of L'oracolo di Messenia by Antonio Vivaldi there's:

Act 2 Scene 7 Son qual nave as in the [following link](https://www.allmusic.com/album/vivaldi-loracolo-in-messenia-mw0002411225)